# Client-side validation for radio buttons in php

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to create a form with multiple radio buttons. I'm generating radio buttons using a for loop like so:

```
<form name="myForm" method="POST" id="myForm" action="result.php" onsubmit="">
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); $i++)
{ ?>
    <input type="radio" name="opt<?php echo $i; ?>" id="opt<?php echo $i; ?>" value="A"/><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="opt<?php echo $i; ?>" id="opt<?php echo $i; ?>" value="B"/> <?php } ?>
```

I want to make sure that for each radio button group, there is 1 selected answer. I've been searching endlessly and I've come up with this code:

```
</script><script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
var x = "<?php echo $j;?>";

var formValid = false;
for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++)
{
    var y = document.getElementsByName("opt"+i);        
    var j = 0;
    while (!formValid && j < y.length){
        if (y[j].checked) {
            formValid = true;
            j++;
            alert("test");
        }
        break;
    }   
}

if (!formValid) { alert("all fields required");
    return false;
}
else
{
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    form.submit();
}</script>
```

My problem with this is even if all the radio buttons have been ticked, all fields required still pops up and the form would submit. Is there something I'm missing here? Please help. I've been stuck with this for days.

Comment: make sure each group of radio buttons have same name attribute value name="radioGroupOne"  name="radioGroupTwo" then it will work

Comment: They do have the same name. I've already checked so I'm not sure why it's not working. I changed something in my code, particularly var j = i to var j = 0. This made some sort of improvement however, if I already have about 3 radios ticked, the form already submits even though there are still radios to be ticked.

Comment: can you paste the markup generated by your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've found once checked field, you're never checking the rest, assuming all is well.

You want to check the fields individually, bailing when you see one that *isn't* valid.

```
var formValid = true;
for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++)
{
    var fieldValid = false;
    var y = document.getElementsByName("opt"+i);        
    var j = 0;
    while (!fieldValid && j < y.length){
        if (y[j].checked) {
            fieldValid = true;
            break;
        }
        j++;
    }   

    if (! fieldValid)
    {
      formValid = false;
      break;
    }
}
```